# Suitable use of Tuple<>, in a unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-4.0, tuples

Whilst writing a set of unit tests (for an existing legacy component), I wanted a way to associate a list of error codes (which will be returned by a service that I have mocked), and a list of corresponding error messages (which my component under test will return).

It seems that using a `List<Tuple<string, string>>` is a nice simple way to define this association.

```
var errorCodesAndMessages = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
{
    Tuple.Create("CODE1", "Error message 1"),
    Tuple.Create("CODE2", "Error message 2")
    // etc...
};
```

In my unit test I can then loop through the `errorCodesAndMessages`, setting up my mocked service to return the *nth* error code, and asserting that the component under test returns the *nth* error message.

Is this a good use of — or an abuse of — `Tuple<>`?

### Edit

Responses have suggested that `Dictionary<string, string>` would be better in this scenario. I have to agree. However, what if (for some reason) we needed to associate three pieces of data (e.g. an error code, user-displayed error message and technical error message)

Would this then be a good use of `Tuple<>`?

```
Tuple.Create("CODE1", "User error message", "Technical error message")
```

Comment: It is OK but I would probably use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` since I would probably need to look up the error from the code (and I imagine codes are unique).

Comment: It's mainly a DRY issue.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - can you elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Tuple still could work, but if you are wanting to track details about the error codes, I think the code would be more readable and maintainable if you created a simple class to compose the details of the error code and still use a dictionary to keep track of the error code keys.

```
Dictionary<string, ErrorCodeDetails>
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that `Dictionary<string, string>` would be a better way to handle it, since it's fairly safe to assume that you won't have duplicate error codes. `Dictionary` also has the advantage of constant-time lookups on the key.

```
var errorCodesAndMessages = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "CODE1", "Error message 1" },
    { "CODE2", "Error message 2" },
    // etc...
};
```

The code is shorter too.

Comment: Only for 2 elements.